# OutOfRangeError when reading TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using

```
tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=v))
```

to create `tf.train.Example` examples for my `TFRecordDataset`. Generating the dataset is working find but I am getting an `OutOfRangeError` whenever I try to run a training step with it.

This is how I am creating the dataset:

```
for agent in agents_provider.agents:

    input_dim = 12 * 8 * 8
    output_dim = agent.encoder_decoder.encoding_size

    def map_example(proto):
        keys_to_features = {
            'inputs': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=(input_dim, ), dtype=tf.float32),
            'targets': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=(output_dim, ), dtype=tf.float32)
        }
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(proto, keys_to_features)
        return parsed['inputs'], parsed['targets']

    dataset = (
        tf.data.TFRecordDataset(glob.glob(os.path.join(shards_directory, '*.train.shard')))
            .map(map_example, num_parallel_calls=cpu_count())
            # .repeat()
            .batch(1)
            .make_one_shot_iterator()
    )
```

but running it:

```
nxt = dataset.get_next()

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
result = session.run(nxt)
```

will throw me this:

```
Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/selfplay.py", line 195, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/selfplay.py", line 171, in main
    inputs, targets = dataset.get_next()
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 421, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2069, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at /media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/selfplay.py:171)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?,768], [?,16]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

I just don't get what the problem is ..

---

Changint `map_example()` to

```
def map_example(proto):
    features = {
        'inputs': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32),
        'targets': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32)
    }
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(proto, features)
    return parsed['inputs'], parsed['targets']
```

will give:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at /media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/selfplay.py:170)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

Comment: This looks strange to me: output_shapes=[[?,768], [?,16]]

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: @ScottSkiles So, the input are supposed to be 768 float32 vectors and the targets are 16-dimensional. Do you mean it's weird that both are described as `output_shapes`? Because that's indeed a little weird. I updated my question with the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def main():

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([])

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    get_next = iterator.get_next()

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        batch = session.run(get_next)
        print(batch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Will give you this error:

```
Caused by op 'IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/opt/pycharm/pycharm-2018.1.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/tmp.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/tmp.py", line 10, in main
    get_next = iterator.get_next()
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 421, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2069, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/stefan/miniconda3/envs/chessai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at /media/Data/workspaces/git/chessai/chessai/tmp.py:10)  = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```